# Unable to get parameters out correctly in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, controller, fixnum

I have the following controller code:

```
@question_group = QuestionGroup.find(params[:id])
@old_order = @question_group.ordering
@new_order = params[:ordering].to_i
  if @old_order < @new_order
```

The parameters include this:

```
Parameters: { "ordering"=>"16", "course_id"=>"8"}
```

The trouble is that originally the params[:ordering] was not a Fixnum. That's why I added to_i. Now it is a Fixnum but it's always 0. I don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If `params[:ordering]` is in fact the String `"16"`, then `params[:ordering].to_i` should return the Fixnum `16`.

I would add debugging information and make sure to check the value of `params[:ordering]`. It very well could be `nil`.  If it is nil, then `params[:ordering].to_i` will return 0.

Comment: Yes it is nil but I don't know why. The params being sent are correct; I can see that from the log. But when I try to access it using params[:ordering] I seem to get nil.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using a form_for and it was creating the `name=model[:ordering]` in the html. Even though it showed up in the log as `ordering=>"3"`, in order to access the params in the controller I needed `params[:model][:ordering]`.